# Does the sequence $a_n=\frac{1}{2^n}{n \choose k}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis

Does the sequence
$a_n=\frac{1}{2^n}{n \choose k} $converge ?

My attempt:
$
\frac{1}{2^n}{n \choose k}\leq \frac{n!}{2^n}=  0 or \infty $??

Thanks for your help.

Edit: Problem solved

Comment: NB: $$\frac{n!}{2^n}\to\infty.$$

Comment: Note that $\binom{n}{k} \leqslant n^k$.

Comment: Ah ok I think I see it Thanks ! But why is n factorial greater than 2 to the n ? Thanks anyway

Comment: Just write down explicitly the product of $n!$ and $2^n$. It should be quite clear why $n! > 2^n$ (assuming $n>3$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\binom{n}{k}/2^n \leq n^k/2^n$. Next, note that $\lim_{n\to \infty} n^k/2^n = 0$, for instance by L'Hôpital and induction on $k$.